# How to insert tab in awk system() command string

Tags: shell, awk

The title is all I want to ask. I've tried:

```
awk 'BEGIN {system("echo a\tb")}'
awk 'BEGIN {system("echo a  b")}'   # embedded tab
```

they both output 'a[space]b', not 'a[tab]b'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both commands call `echo` with two parameters, `a` and `b`; The two parameters are separated with a TAB but, as in any regular shell, the command does not see the space separating the parameters.

What you must do is call `echo` with one parameter: the string `"a<tab>b"`

```
awk 'BEGIN {system("echo \"a\tb\"")}'
```

Comment: I of course tried with the `echo -e` to _enable ... backslash escapes_: `awk 'BEGIN {system("echo -e a\tb")}'` but it didn't go as planned.  Don't I feel like a leprechaun. ++

Comment: the first time I tried `awk 'BEGIN {system("echo 'a\tb'")}'`, and I know to make it work, it's gonna be pretty ugly, like: `awk 'BEGIN {system("echo '"'"'a\tb'"'"'")}'`,  so I avoided the quotes in the first place.

Comment: @JamesBrown Assuming your shell understand `echo -e`, you need to escape your backslash so that it is not interpreted by `awk`

Comment: @xhienne I know, but the feeling when you see `-e a b` on your screen and feel like a dumbass.

Comment: @JamesBrown This is due to `awk` executing `/bin/sh` and not `/bin/bash`. I tried to set the `SHELL` environment variable but to no avail. If you known how to call `bash` instead of `sh` with `system()` (other than `system(bash -c)`) I'd be glad to know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to shell quote it:

```
awk 'BEGIN {system("echo \47a\tb\47")}'
```

Answer (score 0):

@pdg: Try following too:

```
awk -vs1="\"" 'BEGIN{system("echo " s1 "a\tb" s1)}'
```

Where s1 is awk's variable where we need not to use escape sequence inside system command. Here we are escaping the string (") inside s1 variable and then simply printing all variables inside system(function of awk).